# extending background to edges of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure why this is so difficult but I am trying to extend the light grey background to the edge of the screen on the title. See [here](http://ceowatermandate.org/test/title-background-to-cover-width/).

I tried using `background:cover` and creating a `div` outside of the title `div`. Any ideas? note: this is in WordPress. Maybe I should be using JavaScript or JQuery?

I already tried this:

```
.bg-wraf {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  position: ;
  width: 100%;
  background: cover;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected your website and managed to add a div and apply the background-color to achieve the expected result. You need to put your background color `div` outside of the `container` `div`.

### HTML

```
<div class="main_content">
  <div class="bg_grey">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        ..include all your divs that you want inside bg-grey
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.bg_grey {
  background-color: grey; // your background color here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Inspect Element and see which divs you'd need to edit to make this possible. It looks like the header that you want to have the background at 100% width is nestled in other divs, which you are then restrained to their properties.

Answer (score 1):

The background will only extend as far as the element reaches.  You first have to get the element to take up the space you want to cover, and then `background: cover` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that your element is in a BootStrap `.container` class that has a fixed width:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%; /* 1170px on your site, 50% is for this example */
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg-wraf {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px; /* for clarity */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-wraf">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dolor leo, tempor a magna dictum, rutrum sollicitudin nulla. Fusce pretium at turpis eget laoreet. Ut auctor risus sed felis feugiat, nec mollis elit dapibus. Sed eu feugiat turpis. Vivamus
    sed rhoncus libero. Integer cursus nibh ut orci imperdiet pretium.
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll probably want to 'escape' from that container, then possibly use the `.container` class again from inside of the `.bg-wraf` class:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%; /* 1170px on your site, 50% is for this example */
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg-wraf {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 0; /* For clarity */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Content padded but no background
</div>
<div class="bg-wraf">
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dolor leo, tempor a magna dictum, rutrum sollicitudin nulla. Fusce pretium at turpis eget laoreet. Ut auctor risus sed felis feugiat, nec mollis elit dapibus. Sed eu feugiat turpis. Vivamus
    sed rhoncus libero. Integer cursus nibh ut orci imperdiet pretium.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    Content padded but no background
</div>
```

Also note that you have a BootStrap column offset class on `.bg-wraf`, which shouldn't be used in order to obtain a full width.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but it works.

I found the issue was that two containers were being carried over from the header.php file.

So I just closed these off at the top of the template file with two  . Then added them again after the title. Similar to what Obsidian said but the main issue was not knowing that the container was in the header.php file.

Obsidian pretty much pointed to the issue, without mentioning the possiblity of code being in the header.php. So excepting his answer.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: TEST Template.
 *
 * @version 1.0.
 */

get_header('tall');
the_post(); ?>

</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset- bg-wraf" style="background-color: 
#f2f2f2 !important;">
    <?php
```

...

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
```